# Combining two very similar queries with different WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 SQL queries I'm looking to combine. The only difference between the 2 queries is there WHERE Clause.

```
SELECT plateNo,
       SUM(cardno) AS workingcards_1
FROM 
      (select a.plateNo,
      COUNT(DISTINCT cardno) as cardno
from(select *, use_time
     from card_reader)cr
Inner join meter m
    ON cr.use_time BETWEEN m.start and m.end
    WHERE cr.case IN (first, second, third)
GROUP BY m.plateNo)
GROUP BY plateNo;
```

Second

```
SELECT plateNo,
       SUM(cardno) AS workingcards_2
FROM 
      (select a.plateNo,
      COUNT(DISTINCT cardno) as cardno
from(select *, use_time
     from card_reader)cr
Inner join meter m
    ON cr.use_time BETWEEN m.start and m.end
    WHERE cr.case NOT IN (first, second, third)
GROUP BY m.plateNo)
GROUP BY plateNo;
```

The Output I am looking for is something like this

| plateNo | Workingcard_1 | Workingcard_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AZ1 | 13 | 1 |
| AZ2 | 4 | 4 |
| AZ3 | 20 | 15 |

Comment: You tagged both mysql and oracle-sqldeveloper. MySQL cannot be used from Oracle SQLDeveloper. Which database are you really using?

Comment: I am using oracle

Comment: What do you mean by "combine" the two queries? The two queries could be combined into one if you use `WHERE cr.case IS NOT NULL`. Would that give you the result you want? If not, describe the result you want.

Comment: @BillKarwin The result I want is 3 columns. The first column is the plate number, first is the result from the first query and third is the result from the second query

Comment: These queries do not even run. Edit your question to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "union all" between the 2 querys

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION statemnt between the two statements if you don't have duplicate records, UNION ALL if you have duplicate ones.